# What are the rules when writing an article on Super User?

Tags: discussion, questions

I have been working on a topic for quite some time, and now I was wondering is there a problem to share my knowledge via a Super User question? What I mean is, I do a question and answer it myself with all the "research" I've done. Is this okay?

Also, are links related to original articles considered as doing promotion for that related website?

Any other information or advice would be highly appreciated.

Comment: See also: http://superuser.com/help/self-answer.

Comment: The first rule of the QA is that you don't talk about about articles, but Questions and Answers

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Source [How do I write a good answer?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer)

> **Provide context for links**
>
> Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context
>   around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is
>   and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an
>   important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes
>   permanently offline.

---

Source [How to reference material written by others](https://superuser.com/help/referencing)

> When you find a useful resource that can help answer a question (from
>   another site or in an answer on Super User) make sure you do all of
>   the following:
>
> - Provide a link to the original page or answer
> - Quote only the relevant portion
> - Provide the name of the original author

---

Related questions/resources:

[Would a link be considered as a spam?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/9397/would-a-link-be-considered-as-a-spam)

[Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer)